# Eclipse Windows View Issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I just happened to click something on my eclipse. The server window went to the right of my screen. How do I reset it to default, at the bottom of my screen? See image in link below.

[image]

Comment: Just drag and drop it on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [resetting the perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-9j.htm?cp=0_3_2_9):

- Open the **General > Perspectives** preference page.
- From the **Available perspectives** list, select the perspective you want to restore.
- Click **Reset**.
- Click **OK**.